# Put View Controller in TabBar ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tabbarcontroller

I am Create already three view controller & i want to just add those view controller in tabBarview controller.
The view controller is below

First --> Login Page

Second --> Tabbar View controller

```
            1)---> Employee View controller
            2)---> Task View Controller
            3)----> Home View controller
```

I am create above three view controller separate. I want add those in tab bar controller using Interface Builder or coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can find more descriptive example from Apple docs - [Combined View Controller Interfaces](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html)

I assume that Login Page is your root view controller here. Where `_tabBar`, `_window` and `_loginvVewController` are globally declared in the appDelegate headers files. You can also take `_loginvVewController` locally inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method depend upon your requirements.

**AppDelgate.h**

```
UIWindow *_window;
UITabBarController *_tabBar;
LoginViewController *_loginvVewController;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.loginvVewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    [self.window addSubview:self.loginvVewController.view]; 

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)initializeTabbar {

    /*
     * Set up controllers for the tab bar controller
     */
    EmployeeViewController *vc1 = [[[EmployeeViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"View 1"] autorelease];
    TaskViewController *vc2 = [[[TaskViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"View 2"] autorelease];
    HomeViewController *vc3 = [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"View 3"] autorelease];

    // View Controller with each Navigational stack support.
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:vc1];

    /*
     * Set up tab bar controller
     */
    self.tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; 
    self.tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, vc2, vc3, nil];

    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBar.view];
}
```

In my quick hackathon for this problem, I have taken the button "Click here!" on login page - once you click on it will navigate you inside the app with tabbar. If you need the sample project then email me at d3minem@gmail.com.

After many requests via email - I have created the demo project and upload here. https://github.com/Deminem/SimpleTabbarApp--iPhone-

Please vote if you find it useful.

Good luck!

Comment: it gives Black screen. what can i do can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to create a TabBarContoller based application and add the ViewControllers to the TabbarViewController.

Comment: Creating a tab bar controller and configuring it takes much less time than opening up a brand new project and import all the existing code and reconfiguring the build settings, etc…

Answer (score 0):

The path is straight forward.

In IB, place your tabbar controller where you like it, make it have three pages and set their view controller classes.

Or in code, just add the tab bar controller with those three controllers set as its view controllers.